# Build a webpage with a flock of birds flying endlessly around on it

Tags: javascript, web, graphics, webgl

I would like to build a webpage with a flock of birds flying around on it. White background, black, ["bird-shapes"](http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/261388/223877011/stock-vector-a-flock-of-flying-birds-vector-223877011.jpg) to begin with - I'm thinking folding triangles. Eventually I would be interested to generate random flying patterns but for now I would be happy to make regular, repeating patterns, with one "bird" to begin.

I'm wondering how might this best be achieved or where to begin? I have plenty of programming experience with Java, and some in HTML/JavaScript. But I'm interested to learn. I'm just looking for a few pointers. WebGL? Or just use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet is html 5's canvas tag. Canvas also supports WebGL, so using that would be easy too.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/flying-bird-animation
&
http://cssdeck.com/labs/o1jukgxc
You can use this idea to replicate your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. These are very helpful in getting my hands dirty asap, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the effect you're looking for.  If you want a 3d effect you should look into THREE.js.  [This](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs291/) tutorial is a pretty decent introduction.  Personally I think you could do what you need using the 2d canvas.  Daniel Shiffman's [Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/) is a great tutorial on vehicles, all with the standard canvas context.  Most of the examples have been translated into JavaScript (using p5.js), but it's originally in Java so it could be a great way to get your feet wet.

Comment: I think 2d is fine for the moment, thank you for the consideration. I will take a look at that book thanks!